# Error:Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariant.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List;' android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I updated my android studio to :

```
Android Studio 3.0
Build #AI-171.4408382, built on October 20, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 8.1 6.3
```

and my `build.gradle` is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        //Lambda
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.6.1'
        //butterKnife
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And  :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.xx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //Support Library
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    // Web Libs
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    //Rx
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.3'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.16.1'
    // Font Icons
    compile 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-fontawesome:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-material:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-material-community:2.2.2'
    //Butternife
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    //Font
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
}
```

But get me bellow error :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved my problem . I removed :

```
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
```

And :

```
//Lambda
classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.6.1'
//butterKnife
classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'
```

And add :

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

Comment: where to add this vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true in gradle?

Comment: Was your butterknief anotations working after adding 'vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true' in ur code?

Comment: in build.gradle(Module:app) and here : android {
    ..
   ...
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

Comment: But don't install android studio 3 . I installed and then remove it , it has bug in logcat .

Comment: Actually, i am facing the same issue, which you faced (mentioned above) by you.. but i got this issueafter installing Android 3.0 and gradle 4.1

Comment: I installed android studion 3 and when I use (from Log.i(....)) don't show me true result because I remove it .

Comment: Thanks for the help